# How to debug an "access denied" log

Tags: hooks

I have this condition in access callback:

```
$args = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  return (user_is_anonymous() &&
    !empty($args['idp']) &&
    !empty($args['applicationId']) &&
    !empty($args['language_preference']) &&
    !empty($args['token_url']));
```

however, when accesing the domain accessing

`domain.com/ajax/pathxxx?idp=XXX&applicationId=YYY...` it works, but when using `www.domain.com/ajax/pathxxx?idp=XXX&applicationId=YYY...` (note www prefix), I'm getting `access denied` in the Drupal log.

Is there any way to debug this?

EDIT: The log says "Anonymous user"

Comment: The obvious thing would be you're logged out on domain.com but you're logged in on www.domain.com. Have you tried checking to confirm you definitely are logged out on the www.domain.com?

Comment: Hi @LeighMason, its Incognito Tab, I will add to the description